Rust !ink Tutorial fails
Hi I am very new to Rust and would like to get into !ink smart contracts. I am following a tutorial online ( https://use.ink/getting-started/creating-an-ink-project ) but when I try to test the flipper contract the with cargo test I get these errors. I have absolutely no clue how to fix this.
   Compiling anstyle-parse v0.2.4
   Compiling const_env v0.1.2
   Compiling hyper v1.3.1
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
  --> /home/hago/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/scale-info-2.11.2/src/form.rs:64:39
   |
64 | #[cfg_attr(feature = "schema", derive(JsonSchema))]
   |                                       ^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type
   |
   = note: this error originates in the derive macro `JsonSchema` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0282]: type annotations needed
  --> /home/hago/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/scale-info-2.11.2/src/form.rs:81:39
   |
81 | #[cfg_attr(feature = "schema", derive(JsonSchema))]
   |                                       ^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type
   |
   = note: this error originates in the derive macro `JsonSchema` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

   Compiling wasm-opt-cxx-sys v0.116.0
   Compiling darling v0.20.8
   Compiling jsonrpsee-types v0.22.5
   Compiling scale-typegen v0.1.1
   Compiling tower v0.4.13
For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0282`.
error: could not compile `scale-info` (lib) due to 2 previous errors
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...


You should file an issue with the scale-info crate. Errors emitted from the library like this are not generally the users' fault. Besides an author fix, your options are often limited to using a different version; try cargo update scale-info --precise 2.11.1 or an earlier version.

I tried that suggestion, unfortunately it doesn't work.

It could also be schemars fault (since the error is pointing at their macro). Try downgrading that to an earlier version.

It was schemars fault. Looks like they released a new package 3h ago which also explains why things worked this morning :/

I've filed an issue: https://github.com/GREsau/schemars/issues/287

This has been fixed in new version: 0.8.19
